# Concurrency: multiprocessing, threading, greenthreads and asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm currently working on Python project that receives a lot os AWS SQS messages (more than 1 million each day), process these messages, and send then to another SQS queue with additional data. Everything works fine, but now we need to speed up this process a lot!

From what we have seen, or biggest bottleneck is in regards to HTTP requests to send and receive messages from AWS SQS api. So basically, our code is mostly I/O bound due to these HTTP requests.

We are trying to escalate this process by one of the following methods:

- Using Python's multiprocessing: this seems like a good idea, but our workers run on small machines, usually with a single core. So creating different process may still give some benefit, since the CPU will probably change process as one or another is stuck at an I/O operation. But still, that seems a lot of overhead of process managing and resources for an operations that doesn't need to run in parallel, but concurrently.
- Using Python's threading: since GIL locks all threads at a single core, and threads have less overhead than processes, this seems like a good option. As one thread is stuck waiting for an HTTP response, the CPU can take another thread to process, and so on. This would get us to our desired concurrent execution. But my question is how dos Python's threading know that it can switch some thread for another? Does it knows that some thread is currently on an I/O operation and that he can switch her for another one? Will this approach absolutely maximize CPU usage avoiding busy wait? Do I specifically has to give up control of a CPU inside a thread or is this automatically done in Python?
- Recently, I also read about a concept called green-threads, using Eventlet on Python. From what I saw, they seem the perfect match for my project. The have little overhead and don't create OS threads like threading. But will we have the same problems as threading referring to CPU control? Does a green-thread needs to warn the CPU that it may take another one? I saw on some examples that Eventlet offers some built-in libraries like Urlopen, but no Requests.
- The last option we considered was using Python's AsyncIo and async libraries such as Aiohttp. I have done some basic experimenting with AsyncIo and wasn't very pleased. But I can understand that most of it comes from the fact that Python is not a naturally asynchronous language. From what I saw, it would behave something like Eventlet.

So what do you think would be the best option here? What library would allow me to maximize performance on a single core machine? Avoiding busy waits as much as possible?

Comment: Asyncio is designed to handle your exact use-case.  It's cooperative multitasking: the task in control continues until it explicitly yields back to the central event loop.  I don't know why you were not pleased with asyncio but it seems to be just what you need.  It's part of the standard Python library and was fairly mature by version 3.7 (V3.10 is now available).  No third-party downloads are required.